# I just want to change the color of my action bar in my android app

Tags: java, android

I just want to change the color of my action bar in my android app,which is orange(as i have set it ),but as I turn on dark mode it changes to black ,I want to set my action bar in dark mode to orange too.

Comment: can you show some code please?

Comment: Have you tried playing with your `styles.xml` theme for Dark Mode?

Comment: @IvanGraza Can you please tell me which attribute to change as I am pretty new to andoroid development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to play with styles set, the primary color or secondary color in both style files to the color you want. The second thing you can do is add a toolbar and you can customize everything about it. As i am writing this i also remembered maybe you can change the parent class in both styles files. Instead of `Parent.DarkActionBar` maybe you can inherit from some other class and you will get only one color for your Action Bar.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i am  pretty new to android dev so some later day i would be able to follow your instruction.

Comment: It would mean to make the answer as correct.

Comment: @Siddhantsarkar accept his answer (grey tick) if it worked for you